# Visa Requirement - At least 2 spread blank visa pages

Tags: japan, japanese-visitors

I have recently come across the Passport Requirement at the Consulate of Japan in Sydney's website asking for at least 2 spread blank visa pages. I am a bit confused with this as i do have several empty pages in my Passport but i am not having 2 spread (consecutive) blank visa pages. Does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: It is a common requirement with stick visas, usually put into odd page (and immigration stamps on left page, but thing will get messier). I assume if they cancel your visa, they need some space near the original visa) You may need to get a new passport.

Comment: Giacomo Catenazzi ... i have travelled more than 30 countries over the past 10 years and the maximum i came across is a requirement of more than one blank page. This sounds really strange that the Consulate requires 2 spread blank pages. In fact, i checked the Embassy's and other Japanese Consulate websites and couldn't find such a requirement ... this is particular to Sydney Consulate.

Finally, its still 3 years to my Passport Expiry and it becomes really difficult to explain to the authorities for a renewal when a number of single pages are still left in Passport.

Comment: Ok. Russia requires two page, but not spread.

Answer (score 4):

While indeed this is not something other Japan consulates require, alas there is extremely little you can do. You might want to talk to them and ask politely but they might have their own reason, some machine they use, for example.

Let me note this is a very common requirement for other countries as well. For example, this Tripadvisor [thread](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g186216-i15-k8407969-Two_blank_pages_facing_each_other_in_passport_for_UK_visa-United_Kingdom.html) mentions it for a UK visa. This [blog post](https://thepointsguy.com/guides/6-very-important-things-to-know-about-your-passport/) says

> Additionally, several countries require at least two blank pages in order to get a visa. For example, South Africa requires Americans who are staying beyond 90 days to obtain a visa, and the passport’s two blank pages must be adjacent. China will issue a six-month visa to a passport with any two blank pages, but in order to receive a 10-year visa, the pages need to be consecutive.

[Making Your Passport Last Longer When Running Short Of Pages](https://www.executivetraveller.com/making-your-passport-last-longer-when-running-short-of-pages) recommends Post It notes to save double blank pages:

> However, if you notice your passport is starting to fill up, grab those sticky notes, write a short and polite message, and stick them in your passport.
>
> I’ve been travelling with these in my passport for over a year now to preserve my last remaining ‘double blank’ page, and all the passport officers I’ve encountered have been most obliging.
>
> Some smile, some laugh and some say nothing at all, but whatever their approach, the interaction has always finished with their stamp being placed somewhere other than those valuable blank pages: typically near other stamps to maximise space, which I always appreciate.
>
> Just one tip: don’t physically write on your passport visa pages (even in pencil), because doing so could render your passport defaced and invalid

The [image](https://media.executivetraveller.com/900,608-5ac72deaca60494b8d1f6048dd799463-passport-sticky-note.jpg) shows a double blank page with one post it notes on each page, the left one says "Please kindly stamp on any other page. Saving space for one visa." and an arrow to the left and an arrow to the right and then the other page has "space for visa" with the same arrows.